# How to create a many-many relationship in Excel's data model?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, excel-2016

We have an issue with power BI where we cannot use a many-many relationship to do calculations.

**End goal is `Column E`:**
[image]

**Initial Table #1:**

[image: Inventory]

**Initial Table #2:**

[image: Purchases]

When I use the `Average Price per Area of Initial Table #2` on the `Initial Table #1[Item]` as the `Rows` element, I will get a warning: `Relationships between tables maybe needed.` But the issue is Power Bi in Excel does not support a many-many relationship yet.

As can be seen, the Pivot Table is not displaying correctly as there is no item green. I have another database with more SKUs and it's all displaying `#NUM` there because it cannot reference the items despite having the same name.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a third table that contains unique items, i.e,

```
Table 3:

Column "Item"
Blue
Green
Red
...
```

Then connect both initial tables to it using field "Item".

Put "Item" from the third table on pivot rows, and your report should work (assuming your DAX formulas are correctly written).